# Why do Google Images and YouTube work although I have images / Flash blocked?

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, images, flash, google-search

I use a couple add-ons for Firefox that block Flash and images if I choose them to.

However, they work well when I do a Google search for images and watch YouTube videos. How could it be that those get by the blocking of images if images and Flash are disabled?

I am using Firefox 8 and Windows XP with images off by default and using the Flashblock add-on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read some more and did some searching and came across a few answers here.

For some reasons sometimes Flash that is in iframs will slip through and be shown when flashblock should be blocking them.

With images and youtube showing in the google search has to do with javascript. I assume the images are being shown using javascript and for whatever reason it bypasses the settings. I disable javascript, no more images shown.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a "trusted" sites for the add-on and firefox. If the sites arnt there, just add them to the block list.

Comment: There is a whitelist in Flashblock but not a block list, by default it is supposed to block all but the whitelist, the search engines are not on the whitelist.